# How to Merge CSV's to flatten data with Pandas

Tags: csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 different CSV's which share a common index. ('ID')

File1 = De-duped of ID's:

```
ID
54634
1004789
7365412
```

File2 = Actions by ID with Timestamp:

```
 ID  TimeStamp   Action
 54634   10/1/2015 12:38 XX
 1004789 9/1/2015 11:14  YY
 1004789 7/4/2015 9:10   ZZ
 7365412 6/11/2015 13:44 WW
 54634   8/1/2015 12:38  YY
 54634   5/1/2015 12:38  ZZ
 54634   3/1/2015 12:38  WW
```

My simple code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents")

data = pd.read_csv('File1.csv')

data1 = pd.read_csv('File2.csv')

pd.merge(File1, File2, on ='ID')
```

The code above results in:

```
        ID        TimeStamp Action
0    54634  10/1/2015 12:38     XX
1    54634   8/1/2015 12:38     YY
2    54634   5/1/2015 12:38     ZZ
3    54634   3/1/2015 12:38     WW
4  1004789   9/1/2015 11:14     YY
5  1004789    7/4/2015 9:10     ZZ
6  7365412  6/11/2015 13:44     WW
```

What I would like to accomplish is to have and end data set which is like: (With the actions being appended to the right of the ID in ascending by the TimeStamp)

```
54634   WW  ZZ  YY  XX
1004789 ZZ  YY      
7365412 WW
```

I have played around with the "concat" quite a bit but haven't really been able to figure it out. (obviously I am not fairly new)

I am not even sure if I can accomplish what I want to do in Pandas.

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for some sort of `groupby`; this should get you close to what you want:

```
m = pd.merge(data1, data2, on ='ID')
m.groupby('ID').Action.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.tolist()))

ID
54634   XX YY ZZ WW
1004789 YY ZZ
7365412 WW
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I think you meant "x" not "s" in the "tolist" but this totally works.  It is in "descending" (the default of the Panda merge)  but I can solve for that.  You rock!